# How to emulate the Linq "First()" function in Transact-Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have a query in a stored procedure which is executed very many times, so it needs to be as efficient as possible (this is just a specific example of the parameterised query, by way of example):

```
select @resultOUT = count(*) from samples where  <some criteria>
```

My problem is with the count(*) part. I only need to know if there is one such row in the table, and as I understand it this query will scan the entire table (or indexes) to count the number of matching rows.

So what I need is a sql equivalent of the Linq First() method - ie "find the first matching row and then forget about the rest."

How would I go about that? I've tried using the EXISTS keyword, and I keep running into syntax difficulties, eg

```
   select @resultOUT = EXISTS (select somekeycolumn from samples where <somecriteria>)
```

which describes what I want, but is incorrect.

Can anyone put me on the right path?

I will need to do something similar for Oracle too, by the way.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
SELECT @resultOUT = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(select * from samples where <somecriteria>) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will be slightly different:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM samples WHERE <somecriteria> ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  INTO :result_out
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me why this won't compile?  execute immediate  'select CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from samples where samplecode = :samplecode  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString || ') then 1 else 0 end into :varResult from DUAL'
using varSampleCode, varResult ;    Assume the variables are all declared and the query itself makes sense.

Comment: @NeilHaughton, I'm not sure why that wouldn't compile, but it sounds like a separate question from the OP.

Comment: It's not really a second question IMHO because I am asking why the suggested answer doesn't compile. In any event, I did post a second question, which gave me the answer.

Comment: @NeilHaughton, are you saying my answer doesn't compile? Because my answer and what you posted in your comment as not compiling are wildly different.

Comment: No, I'm asking why my use of what you suggested doesn't compile (my post 5th Feb 12:15UCT, which is using your suggestion within an execute direct command).